# Can I replace Razor page generation with custom without redirection in Middleware?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to stop the requested routes' Razor page response generation globally under certain conditions, and replace it with something else.

Using the following middleware I'm able to rewrite the response body and view it in the browser but the original requested page is still processed, specifically the Constructor and the OnGet handler, which I don't want. Is there a way to bypass the processing of the original page, using Filters perhaps? I'm trying to avoid redirection if possible. I'm using dotnet core 3.1.

```
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBody = context.Response.Body;

            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                // todo better as a filter?
                var html = "<html><body><h3>We are processing your login...</h3></body></html>";
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(html);
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

                await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are these conditions? `_next(context);` is calling your `OnGet()`

Comment: Whether the user has been visually processed for authorisation to see the page or should be redirected to a legacy site. If they haven’t, the plan is to intercept any page request, bypass the page generation and display the processing page.

Comment: Could you explain more detailed what authorization conditions you require? If user is authenticated you can get user claims from `HttpContext.User.Claims`. And if conditions are not met, just do not call `_next(context)`

Comment: They are arbitrary business logic conditions that decide if the user should be redirected to a legacy system, and there is a requirement for this to be displayed in the UI. If I don't call _next(context) wouldn't that mean the remaining middleware in the pipeline wouldn't execute?

Comment: If you don't call _next(context), then next middleware steps are not executed. I guess that's what you wanted - to bypass processing of the original page.

Comment: It seems you want to show the processing page when the login happened and then after your server processing completely then show the details page inside the browser, if this is your requirement, I suggest you could use ajax or else achieve this requirement instead of doing this things inside the server side, you could show processing html firstly by using js and then using the ajax to get the next page and then show it inside the browser.